# OpenCart passing from controller to view

Tags: php, opencart

New to OpenCart and am having issues.
I'm Trying to get the sum of a column from a table and display it on a page. I've tried a few iterations of the following but always get an undefined variable error. I've been stuck on this for a while and am not sure what Im doing wrong.

my model:

```
 public function getSum() {
        $amount_total = $this->db->query("SELECT FROM oct_donate SUM(amount) as amount_sum");
        $sums = $amount_total->row["amount_sum"];
        return $sums; 
        }
```

my controller:

```
public function sum() {

        $data['total_sum']=$this->load->model('revenue/order')->getSum();      

    }
```

view: `<?php echo $total_sum;  ?>`

Comment: Your query still has bad syntax.  You want "SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM oct_donate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your controller code. You have to load the model first and then call its method. Update the code.

```
public function sum() {
  $this->load->model('revenue/order')
  $data['total_sum']=$this->model_revenue_order->getSum();
}
```

Also your query is not correct. I think you missed to select columns. It should be

```
$this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM oct_donate");
```

Comment: thanks, I made the changes but still getting undefined variable error.